# How to do multiple selection rows after insertion of NSTableVeiw

Tags: macos, select, insert, nstableview, rows

I'm working on a Mac app and dealing with NSTableView to show a playlist. Users could add  songs to the table (or remove from). It supports undo/redo operations.

Here is the part of my code:

```
// MyDocument.m

- (void)insertObject:(URSoundTrack *)object inSoundTracksAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index{

    [[self.undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] removeObjectFromSoundTracksAtIndex:index];
    [self.undoManager setActionName:@"Add sound track"];

    [self.soundTracks insertObject:object atIndex:index];
}

- (void)removeObjectFromSoundTracksAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index{
    URSoundTrack *soundTrack = [self.soundTracks objectAtIndex:index];

    [[self.undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] insertObject:soundTrack inSoundTracksAtIndex:index];
    [self.undoManager setActionName:@"Remove sound track"];

    [self.soundTracks removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}
```

Those two methods are antagonistic for undo/redo, and it works perfectly.

But I want to make the table view select the just-added rows after insertion. It should also work when undoing a deletion or redoing a insertion (to insert the objects).

I tried some ways but they didn't work. I want to know how to make the table view select those rows after insertion (even when undoing/redoing to insert the rows)?

==== Updated ====

There could be more than one object to be inserted during one operation, even if undoing or redoing, in my app. I need to select all of those rows which were just inserted. I did try `–selectRowIndexes:byExtendingSelection:` method with my insertion method, but only one selection in the first invoked insertion method would work.

I don't know how to make the multiple selection after inserting some objects within my `–insertObject:inSoundTracksAtIndex:` method.

Answer (score 0):

NSTableView gives you a nice API for selecting rows:

[`selectRowIndexes:byExtendingSelection:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTableView/selectRowIndexes%3abyExtendingSelection%3a)

You know which rows have been inserted, just pass along an index set of them (with a "`byExtendingSelection:`" parameter of "`NO`", if you want to create a brand new selection) and everything will be lovely.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I did try before. But I need to do multiple selection within my insertion method, and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I've tried the `-selectRowIndexes:byExtendingSelection:` in my insertion method, but that selection method would only work once at the first invocation of the multiple insertion within one operation in the same run loop.
How could I make the multiple selection happen after multiple insertion?

Comment: you can *extend* the selection (i.e. make multiple selections) by changing that last parameter, "`byExtendingSelection:`", to "`YES`".